# Celery - Only one instance per task/process?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

In the celery docs, section Instantiation (http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes) the following is stated:

> A task is not instantiated for every request, but is registered in the task registry as a global instance.
>
> This means that the init constructor will only be called once per process, and that the task class is semantically closer to an Actor.

Nevertheless, when I run the following example I see that the **init** method is called at least 3 times. What is wrong in the setup? The `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1` should make sure that there is only one process per worker, right?

`$ celery -A proj beat`

```
celery beat v3.1.17 (Cipater) is starting.
init Task1
40878160
x=1.0
init Task1
40878352
x=1.0
init Task1
40879312
x=1.0
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2015-02-05 23:05:21,875: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2015-02-05 23:05:21,971: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task    task1-every-5-seconds (proj.tasks.t1)
[2015-02-05 23:05:26,972: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task task1-every-5-seconds (proj.tasks.t1)
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
             broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['proj.tasks'])
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS=True,
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=60,
    CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1,
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
        'task1-every-5-seconds': {
            'task': 'proj.tasks.t1',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5)
            },
        },
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'GMT',
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from proj.celery import app
from celery import Task
import time

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Task1(Task):
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self):
        print "init Task1"
        print id(self)
        self.f = Foo(1.0)
        print "x=1.0"

@app.task(base=Task1)
def t1():
    t1.f.x +=1
    print t1.f.x
```

Comment: Please state why you want the `__init__` to be called once. There may be other ways around. `__init__` is not a constructor, it is initiator of an instance. If you want to make sure the exact same instance of the task invokes `__init__` multiple times, print `id(self)` as well.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz when calling `__init__` I open a connection with a socket and this task should be performed only once per instance. Should I put a check in place (e.g. if connection already open, do nothing) or should I try adding this in the `__new__` ? I was using the `__init__` because in the docs it is said that it is called only once. I will check about the print id(self) and update the question soon. Thanks

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz Edited, printing id(self) while calling `__init__` there are 3 different instances of the class. Shouldn't there be only 1? I am a bit confused with the documentation and setup. Any thoughts?

Comment: so those are, in fact 3 different instances. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as per your comment, you need to maintain one connection per thread.

Why not to use a thread storage then? It *should* be a safe solution in your case.

```
from threading import local

thread_storage = local()

def get_or_create_conntection(*args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(thread_storage, 'connection'):
        thread_storage.connection = Connection(*args, **kwargs)
    return thread_storage.connection

@app.task()
def do_stuff():
    connection = get_or_create_connection('some', connection='args')
    connection.ping()
```